# Search results number different on 2 SharePoint environments

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

We have 2 SharePoint Server 2013 search dedicated environments, Env A and Env B.

We've created the same content source on both farms and performed indexing. Both indexings completed successfully with the same results.

When we perform search on Env A, all results are being returned, but on Env B, only few results are returned.

What could be the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason often is that that Search result web part settings are different, the duplicate trimming is the main suspect

However try running the same query against both using the Sharepoint search query tool. If your results differs you have an index problem

Comment: Duplicate trimming deactivation didn't resolve the problem.